# EF Migrations with Azure Pipeline Tasks

Tags: entity-framework, powershell, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

It appears to me that it's not straight forward to get migrations running with a yaml build pipeline with tasks because I'm getting the following error when I try and create a task that runs `dotnet ef` migrations.

```
==============================================================================
Task         : PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
Version      : 2.151.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
##[command]"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\agent\_work\_temp\a2cda363-57d3-416e-80ae-fb82a650ff74.ps1'"
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
##[section]Finishing: Roll back migrations
```

On the build server, I have dotnet-ef installed globally.  So I'm not sure at this point why it's giving me this error.  Below is the yml script.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: "Apply migrations"
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      dotnet ef database update --project $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\DataLayer\DataLayer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that it's a windows user issue.  dotnet core 3 no longer has dotnet-ef built into dotnet and I knew this and installed dotnet-ef as global but apparently doing that is user specific on a machine.  The dev that created the build pipeline needed to add dotnet-ef globally with their user on the same machine to get this working.  Hope this helps someone else in a collaborative environment.

Comment: Can you share your full yml script for reference ?

Comment: I install mine on each build ( using Cake ), but if you always install the tool it's always there for Azure pipelines. Can add it to your c:\<folder> and put it in the path also.

Comment: The yml script is pretty long, it builds several solutions and then runs a bunch of unit/integration testing projects.  It's sensitive so I would prefer to not paste it here.  We found out that it was a user issue on Windows servers since the build/devops server is windows.

Answer (score 10):

I had some confusion until I followed [this](https://clearmeasure.com/run-ef-core-migrations-in-azure-devops/) article.  With CI/CD pipelines there is a clear line between build (CI) and deploy (CD) which EF Migrations straddle.  The build is like baking a pizza and is responsible to produce artifacts, while the release is like delivering the pizza and is responsible to deploy and install the artifacts on the target.  Running `ef database update` in a AzureDevOps build pipeline is like trying to deliver a pizza that is still in the oven--it might work but probably going to burn the car and make folks hangry.

The build phase can't know where or when the artifacts will ever be used, so they need to be packaged with everything they might need.  We also want the freedom to deploy to any supported environment without a new build so that we can react as needed (testing, high volume, disaster recovery, etc).  Further, only the release phase will know the correct database type, its state and secrets until it is actually deployed to the target server, so any DB operations should be its responsibility.

The `ef database update` migration command does 2 tasks:

1. A *CI* task when it generates scripts that can be run on the DB using the connection settings in the active configuration.
2. A *CD* task when it applies the scripts to the target database.

So, we need to split the ef migration into different tasks that can be performed in the appropriate mode.  Fortunately dotnet-ef provides the `ef migrations script` command to package the updates to a file that can be included as a build artifact. We also want to run the migrations only when needed and not wipe out data every time we commit code, so the *idempotent* flag is exactly what we need:

> *idempotent*
> (computing) Describing an action which, when performed multiple times, has no further effect on its subject after the first time it is performed.

Awesome, but we still need to run the dotnet-ef command.  As with the article I had issues with running the *ef*  command as a *dotnet* task, so followed the advice and used a basic *script* command.  The resulting build yaml is:

```
steps:
- script: 'dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef'
  displayName: Install dotnet EF
  
- script: 'dotnet ef migrations script   --idempotent  --output migrations.sql --project pathto\aproject.csproj'
  displayName: Create EF Scripts
 
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy EF Scripts to Staging'
  inputs:
    Contents: |
     **\migrations.sql 
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    flattenFolders: true
    
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

And then in the release, each stage needs to apply the script to the target database.  The real power in this is that the same build can be pushed to multiple servers or environments where any custom configuration can be applied.  In this example, a development Azure SQL instance:

```
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: 'Execute EF Migrations'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
    ServerName: '$(ServerName)'
    DatabaseName: '$(DatabaseName)'
    SqlUsername: '$(SqlUsername)'
    SqlPassword: '$(SqlPassword)'
    deployType: SqlTask
    SqlFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\migrations.sql'
```

Now we can predictably deploy our build to any environment with the click of a button, and we have more time to eat the pizza (once it is done delivering).

Comment: I like this analogy, but we're deploying to linux servers on a self hosted DevOps environment, so we don't have the capacity of a one click button deployment, although it would be nice!  We looked into it and it would require bash scripts on the server and such.  Amazingly, we're developing on macs, we're running the build and unit testing on windows servers, and then deploying to Linux.  It's an interesting project indeed!