# Using Azure DevOps to handle EF Migrations

Tags: .net, entity-framework, azure-devops

When using Visual Studio I just run `Add-Migration Name` and then `Update-Database` .
Now I'm trying to automate some processes using Azure DevOps, I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59761685/ef-migrations-with-azure-pipeline-tasks) and tried to adapt but without success.

My CI pipeline:

```
trigger:
  - master
  - development

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Install DotNet 6.0.x'
  inputs:
    version: '6.0.x'
    includePreviewVersions: true

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Install NuGetTool'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'DotNet restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/**/*.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run XUnit tests'
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/Workio.Tests/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'DotNet publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Install EF tools'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: 'tool'
    arguments: 'install --global dotnet-ef'
  
- script: 'dotnet ef migrations script   --idempotent  --output migrations.sql --project Workio/Workio/Workio.csproj'
  displayName: Create EF Scripts
 
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy EF Scripts to Staging'
  inputs:
    Contents: |
     **\migrations.sql 
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    flattenFolders: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifacts'
```

Problem is that the script created only has EFMigrations_History table.
Can someone help me understanding what I'm doing wrong?

**Update**
I was not creating my migration before using script command.

```
- script: 'dotnet ef migrations add $(MigrationName) --project Workio/Workio/Workio.csproj'
  displayName: 'Add Migrations
```

My problem now is because I'm not saving those migrations anywhere, every next time the release pipeline will run I will get duplicated table errors. How should I handle this?

**Update 2:**
Don't really know why, but I though storing migrations in git was bad working in a team, but [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/teams) and [this (how to handle merge migrations)](https://8thlight.com/insights/entity-framework-and-resolving-team-migration-conflicts) shows me it isn't. So I'll just save migrations into bitbucket.

Comment: Where are you defining the `MigrationName` variable?

Comment: @DanielMann I updated my question with the correct pipeline sorry

Comment: I was missing the task to add migration. But since I'm not storing my migrations folder in my repository how should I handle it? Because if I run it for a second it'll give a error for duplicated tables

Comment: @Lucas Migration scripts are meant to be idempotent, so if you're getting an error about tables-already-exist (or similar) then it means you're not generating migration scripts correctly.

Comment: @Lucas Having said that, automated (and automagically-generated) SQL Migrations sound like a good idea, but in-practice they have a habit of breaking horribly once your database design goes one inch outside of trivial examples, or as soon as you use modern SQL features not yet supported by your tooling (or sometimes even not-even-modern features, like Temporal Tables... ), so overall my point is that you might want to consider _not_ relying on EF for your migration scripts and instead do it the _hard way_  with SSDT (but at least it works).

Comment: @Dai that was basically the problem yes, I already updated my question with new info but basically I, wrongfully, thought we shouldn't keep our migrations in our repo, so I was creating a new one in my pipeline (obviously that won't work well). That being said I would like to replace EF (or at least part of it) aswell but since this is a school project and they asked us to use it I'm stuck with it. Thank you tho

Comment: @Lucas In industry, you keep **all** migration scripts in source-control, just like everything else, because you never know when you need to do an emergency data migration for whatever reason. Ideally you'll have 1 migration script for every distinctly-versioned snapshot of your DB schema, so going from one version (say `3` to `7` is just a matter of playing-back the `3-to-4`, `4-to-5`, `5-to-6`, and `6-to-7` scripts in that order - _assuming nothing goes wrong_, of course).